# How to get day diff of lowest date (column A) and highest date (column B) then display it as Month and Ave WHERE column B IS NOT NULL

Tags: mariadb

How to get day diff of lowest date (column A) and highest date (column B) then display it as Month and Ave WHERE column B IS NOT NULL

I have a table that contains a date in column A and another date in column B.
I need to get the day difference of the lowest date and the highest date and display the month where those two dates occured (group by monthname) and the average day difference if there are multiple entries

Month              Days
November            5
December            7.5

[image]

Comment: Please give us your tables as DDL (`CREATE TABLE foo (...)`) and your data as DML (`INSERT INTO foo VALUES (...)`). There are some articles on how to ask questions here - you might want to take a look? Help us to help you.p.s. welcome to the forum 8-)

Comment: Same results would also help for this set. As you've provided a sample data, include real column names rather than column A, column B in the text. Its hard to correlate.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MIN(a...), MAX(b...)
    FROM tbl AS a
    JOIN tbl AS b  USING (...)  -- the column(s) of the PRIMARY KEY
    GROUP BY ...
    HAVING MAX(b...) IS NOT NULL
```

That ignores rows where b... IS NULL.  In other words, it gives you the last known date.

If you want to throw out the entire group if any b... IS NULL, that gets messier.    Please clarify by providing the info requested in the Comments.